# How to get an SPListItem from a Search Query Programmatically

Tags: search, splistitem, search-results

I'm querying my Search Server and getting some results... How can i get the SPListItem linked to that object?

I tried with many ways, but every method fails..

Here's my code:

```
            string fullsite = SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/sites/ReplyCorp";

            Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite scSite = new SPSite(fullsite))   //Collego impersonificando l'utente
                {
                    using (SPWeb webRoot = scSite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(scSite);
                        keywordQuery.ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults;
                        keywordQuery.RowLimit = 1;
                        keywordQuery.QueryText = "contentId:" + updateContentObj.contentId;
                        ResultTableCollection searchResultTables = keywordQuery.Execute();

                        ResultTable searchResult = searchResultTables[ResultType.RelevantResults];


                        searchResult.Read();                            
                        SPListItem listItem = null; 

                        string url = searchResult["Path"].ToString();
                        Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                        {
                            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url))
                            {
                                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                                {
                                    debug += "MY URL" + web.Url + "PPPPP" + url;

                                    listItem = web.GetListItem(url);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        debug += listItem.Name;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Why do you have `Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate(){});` twice?
Just once is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a way to get that SPListItem... I modified my code this way:

```
 Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite scSite = new SPSite(fullsite))  
                {
                    using (SPWeb webRoot = scSite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        scSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        webRoot.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        SPListItem listItem = null;//= GetItemByContentId(updateContentObj.contentId);

                        KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(scSite);
                        keywordQuery.ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults;
                        keywordQuery.RowLimit = 1;
                        keywordQuery.QueryText = "contentId:" + updateContentObj.contentId;
                        ResultTableCollection searchResultTables = keywordQuery.Execute();

                        ResultTable searchResult = searchResultTables[ResultType.RelevantResults];

                        searchResult.Read();

                        string url = searchResult["Path"].ToString();

                        Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                        {
                            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url))
                            {
                                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                                {
                                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                    site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                                    Match m = Regex.Match(url + "&Pippo", "ID=[0-9]+");
                                    int listItemID = int.Parse(Regex.Match(m.Value, "[0-9]+").Value);
                                    listItem = web.Lists["Contenuti"].Items.GetItemById(listItemID);
                                        }
                            }
                        });

                        debug += listItem.Name;
                    }
                }
            });
            return new ResponseObject() { Message = debug, SPResultStatus = ResponseObjectSPResultStatus.SUCCESS };
        }
```

In simple words i get the ID and the LIST from the URL and then i retrieve manualli the item!

Answer (score 3):

In SharePoint 2013 ListID, ListItemID properties can be added to the result set of KeywordQuery, SearchExecutor:

```
var properties = keywordQuery.SelectProperties;

properties.Add("ListID");
properties.Add("ListItemID");
```

See:
Overview of crawled and managed properties in SharePoint Server 2013
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219630.aspx

Answer (score 0):

ur doing searches not related to listitems...
Your searching your whole site, so it can return lists, listitems, ...
I'd use another way if you want to look for SPListItems...

Comment: But I must search across the whole site collection.. How can i do to "filter" just to SPListItem and look for that? Thank you

Comment: Your comment below is how it's done. (atleast with SPSiteDataQuery, I never user KeyWordQuery)