# Possible to load a SPListItem from the item url?

Tags: list, splistitem, list-item

I have a FullTextSqlQuery that is returning the URL for a list item.  I would like to create a new SPListItem object from that URL.  Is there an easy way to do this, or will I need to peel apart the URL to determine the site/list/listitem?

Comment: I can't imagine there would be any other way than to dissect the URL so that you can get the list. Like SPList list = web.GeList("/Lists/ListPath/"); It's only able to return the full URL?

Answer (score 2):

How about the [SPWeb.GetListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlistitem.aspx) method?

It takes in the server relative or absolute URL and returns a SPListItem object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not verified)

```
using(spsite site = new spsite(url))
{
using(spweb web = site.openweb())
{
string itemurl = url.replace(web.url, "");
itemurl = web.serverrelativeurl + itemurl;
splistitem item = web.getlistitem(itemurl);
}
}
```

Comment: to add: they have a great method in SharePoint, *SPUtility.ConcatUrls*, which allows to assure your urls are combined correctly. it would be a good practice to use it every time you concatenate urls :)

Comment: I don't think that is what he means... It seems he has a full URL for 1 item and he wants to create a new SPItem with that other item's URL.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the SPWeb.GetListItem method doesn't work with list elements but only with files..

I have the same problem, I tried this way:

[How to get an SPListItem from a Search Query Programmatically](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28864/how-to-get-an-splistitem-from-a-search-query-programmatically)

It works but I think it's a little inefficent.