# GetListItem(strUrl) equivalent for ClientContext

Tags: 2010, client-object-model

I know using server side code I can use GetListItem(url) to get an item using a server relative/absolute url ([such as this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31482/possible-to-load-a-splistitem-from-the-item-url)) however I cant seem to find the same code using the Client Object Model.  Can anyone tell me if there is a similar one or do I have to approximate my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in the Client Object Model:

```
var fileItem = Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("server/relative/url");

context.Load(fileItem); //you will probably need to load the ListItemAllFields property here.
context.ExecuteQuery();

var listItem = fileItem.ListItemAllFields; 

Console.WriteLine(listItem["Title"]);
```